# I need help configuring my DHCP server

Tags: ip, dhcp

I'm following this guide [here](https://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/staticlocalip.html), my goal is to set up a home server and I'm currently stuck at DHCP.

I changed my DHCP server to 198.162.2.11, when I run ifconfig I can see that the default gateway and DHCP server are the same, i.e; DHCP & Default Gateway = 198.162.2.11 plus when I navigate to 198.162.2.11 my routers homepage shows up. Is this normal?, are the values for DHCP and Default Gateway meant to be different?

Note: I'm using Linux Ubuntu 14.04LTS and am freaking new to all these, so take it easy on me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Default Gateway = the device your computer(s) will use to acces another network than the one they are currently on (also called "router")
- DHCP = the device your computer(s) will contact when they try to get an IP address for your network

What that means is, the "Default Gateway" and "DHCP" roles are completely independent an can be installed on the same device at the same time. In most home network configuration, the ISP's box is at the same time a router (i.e. Default Gateway, for Internet access) and a DHCP server.

Also, most (if not all) professional routers can be configured to work as a DHCP server.

By accessing your router's IP in a web browser, you can access its configuration page in order to change its settings, this is perfectly normal and what wouldn't be normal is if you *didn't* get that page.